# Return from SwiftUI to Storyboard with a SwiftUI button

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui, storyboard

In an attempt to merge a SwiftUI view and Storyboard I have created a segue from a storyboard into a SwiftUI view, but currently have no way of getting back.

I don't want to do this through a navigation bar, rather a button in my SwiftUI view which unwinds the segue back to the main.storyboard view.

[image: Storyboard View]

The way I have achieved my outcome so far is by using the SwiftUI view as a hosting controller, and then added a segue from the View Controller to the Child Hosting Controller.

The button which I want to unwind the segue looks like this:

```
Button(action: {
    print("button pressed") // UNWIND SEGUE HERE

  }) {
      Image("TopLeft")
      .renderingMode(.original)
      .resizable()
      .scaledToFit()
      .frame(width: 15, height: 15)
  }
}
```

This code is linked to a class called `SecondView` which is the SwiftUI code. SecondView is activated by a subclass ChildHostingController, linked to the UIHostingController on the storyboard:

```
class ChildHostingController: UIHostingController<SecondView> {

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder,rootView: SecondView());
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
}
```

Is there any possible way to unwind the segue back to View Controller?

Much appreciated!!

Comment: Yes it would be something similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69942854/how-to-pass-textfield-value-to-view-controller-through-button-click-in-swift-ui/69945806#69945806) setup.

Comment: Not sure exactly how I would go about this, I cannot understand the code from your example enough to be able to pick out the setup I need

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64403580/pass-variable-from-uiviewcontroller-to-swiftui-view/64404300#64404300) is another example.

Comment: Sorry to be a hassle, but I'm not too sure I fully understand. I would like to unwind a segue first used in a UIViewController, through the use of a button. So tapping on the button in question (which is in SwiftUI) pushes back down the SwiftUI view and on to the UIViewController.

Comment: Your button should call a unwind segue in the UIKit controller. You can use a delegate var in hosting vc that point to the presenting vc. The the hVC could call the pVC to unwind.

Comment: In the first example you would unwind in `loadAds`. That method is called in SwiftUI and the "work" is done in UIKit

Comment: I am not going to write an answer from scratch. Give it a good try and with some updated code and a decent attempt I can give some input. Make sure you provide a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A possible approach is to inject a closure with unwind action from a view controller via view model into SwiftUI view and call it inside SwiftUI view button.

Here is main part:

```
super.init(coder: coder, rootView: SecondView(vm: viewModel))
viewModel.unwind = { [weak self] in
   // call unwind segue created in storyboard
    self?.performSegue(withIdentifier: "unwind_segue_identifier", sender: self)
}
```

Complete [findings and code here](https://github.com/Asperi-Demo/4SwiftUI/blob/master/Answers/Return_to_Storyboard_with_SwiftUI_button.md)

Comment: You never cease to amaze me sir, thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know you must create unwind segues via your main storyboard. However, once you've done that and given it an identifier, you could modify your `UIHostingController` as follows:

```
class ChildHostingController: UIHostingController<SecondView> {

    func dismiss() {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "myUnwindSegueIdentifier", sender: self)
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder,rootView: SecondView())
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.rootView.dismissViewController = dismiss
    }
}
```

In `SecondView` you'd want to define that `dismissViewController` method:

```
var dismissViewController: (() -> Void)?
```

Then call it with your button:

```
Button(action: {
    dismissViewController!()

  }) {
      Image("TopLeft")
      .renderingMode(.original)
      .resizable()
      .scaledToFit()
      .frame(width: 15, height: 15)
  }
}
```