# Using @EnvironmentObject properly

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I am just trying to get my updated value to display in my application after it receives a new value from bluetooth core. I know the value in the class is updating properly because I can see it in my print statement. My problem is that my @EnvironmentObject itself is not updating in the view so its always showing "No Value Yet"

Any help would be appreciated I am new to IOS!

```
import SwiftUI
import CoreBluetooth
import UIKit

let weightScaleCBUUID = CBUUID(string: "0x181D")
let massPoundCharacteristicCBUUID = CBUUID(string: "0x27B8")


class HRMViewController: UIViewController, ObservableObject  {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var bodySensorLocationLabel: UILabel!
    var centralManager: CBCentralManager!
    var weightPeripheral: CBPeripheral!
    @Published var willWork: String = "No Value Yet"
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        centralManager = CBCentralManager(delegate: self, queue: nil)
        // Make the digits monospaces to avoid shifting when the numbers change
    }
    
}

extension HRMViewController: CBCentralManagerDelegate {
    func centralManagerDidUpdateState(_ central: CBCentralManager) {
        switch central.state {
        case .unknown:
            print("central.state is .unknown")
        case .resetting:
            print("central.state is .resetting")
        case .unsupported:
            print("central.state is .unsupported")
        case .unauthorized:
            print("central.state is .unauthorized")
        case .poweredOff:
            print("central.state is .poweredOff")
        case .poweredOn:
            print("central.state is .poweredOn")
            centralManager.scanForPeripherals(withServices: [weightScaleCBUUID])
        @unknown default:
            print("Something is completely wrong here")
        }
    }
    
    func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didDiscover peripheral: CBPeripheral,
                        advertisementData: [String: Any], rssi RSSI: NSNumber) {
        print(peripheral)
        
        // copy the peripheral instance
        weightPeripheral = peripheral
        weightPeripheral.delegate = self
        
        centralManager.stopScan()
        centralManager.connect(weightPeripheral)
        
    }
    
    func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didConnect peripheral: CBPeripheral) {
        if peripheral == weightPeripheral {
            print("Connected!")
            weightPeripheral.discoverServices([weightScaleCBUUID])
        } else {
            print("Something went wrong in didConnect")
        }
        
    }
    
    
}

extension HRMViewController: CBPeripheralDelegate {
    func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didDiscoverServices error: Error?) {
        guard let services = peripheral.services else { return }
        for service in services {
            print(service)
            peripheral.discoverCharacteristics([massPoundCharacteristicCBUUID], for: service)
            
        }
    }
    func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didUpdateValueFor characteristic: CBCharacteristic,
                    error: Error?) {
        switch characteristic.uuid {
        case massPoundCharacteristicCBUUID:
            if let CurrWeightValue = String(bytes: characteristic.value![1...6], encoding: .utf8) {
//                print(CurrWeightValue)
                willWork = CurrWeightValue
                print(willWork)
                //        bodySensorLocationLabel!.text = CurrWeightValue
            } else {
                print("not a valid UTF-8 sequence")
            }
            
            //      let weightValue = weightHelper(from: characteristic)
            //      // print(weightValue)
            //      peripheral.setNotifyValue(true, for: characteristic)
            //      bodySensorLocationLabel.text = weightValue
        default:
            print("Unhandled Characteristic UUID: \(characteristic.uuid)")
        }
    }
    
    func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didDiscoverCharacteristicsFor service: CBService,
                    error: Error?) {
        guard let characteristics = service.characteristics else { return }
        
        for characteristic in characteristics {
            if characteristic.properties.contains(.notify) {
                print("\(characteristic.uuid): properties contains .notify")
                peripheral.setNotifyValue(true, for: characteristic)
            }
        }
    }
    
}

struct HRMViewControllerRepresented: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    
    var centralManager: CBCentralManager!
    var weightPeripheral: CBPeripheral!
    weak var bodySensorLocationLabel: UILabel!
    var willWork = ""
    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> HRMViewController {
        return HRMViewController()
    }
    
    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: HRMViewController, context: Context) {
        uiViewController.centralManager = centralManager
        uiViewController.weightPeripheral = weightPeripheral
        uiViewController.bodySensorLocationLabel = bodySensorLocationLabel
        uiViewController.willWork = willWork
        uiViewController.viewDidLoad()
    }
}


struct SessionsView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var userController: HRMViewController
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            Text("Howdy Number \(userController.willWork)").padding()
            HRMViewControllerRepresented()
            
        }
            
        
        
    }
}

struct SessionsView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        SessionsView().environmentObject(HRMViewController())
    }
}
```

```html
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        TabView {
            HomeView()
                .tabItem() {
                    Image("home-icon")
                        .renderingMode(.template)
                    Text("Home")
                }
            SessionsView().environmentObject(HRMViewController())
                .tabItem() {
                    Image("sessions-icon")
                        .renderingMode(.template)
                    Text("Sessions")
                }
            ReportsView()
                .tabItem() {
                    Image("reports-icon")
                        .renderingMode(.template)
                    Text("Reports")
                }
            SettingsView()
                .tabItem() {
                    Image("settings-icon")
                        .renderingMode(.template)
                    Text("Settings")
                }
        }
        
        
    }
}
```

Comment: Essententially I just need to know how to update a variable and pass it into my view properly. All the rest is not really important. 

Please treat it as if I had a UIViewController with a Published Variable that was getting updated every second. and then the Struct View is attempting to show that updated value everytime it updates. 

Should be very simple yet im struggling!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out it was very simple once I started implementing this protocol:
[Pass variable from UIViewController to SwiftUI View](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64403580/pass-variable-from-uiviewcontroller-to-swiftui-view)

Here is my final implementation using MVVM:

```
    class SharedViewModel: ObservableObject {
        @Published var myString = "---"
        @Published var centralManager: CBCentralManager!
        @Published var weightPeripheral: CBPeripheral!
    }
    
    //Not an extension
    struct UIKitViewController_UI: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
        typealias UIViewControllerType = WSViewController
        var sharedVM: SharedViewModel
        
        func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> WSViewController {
            return WSViewController(vm: sharedVM)
        }
        
        
        func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: WSViewController, context: Context) {
            
        }
        
    }

//My bluetooth Class
class WSViewController: UIViewController {
    let sharedVM: SharedViewModel
    var weightPeripheral: CBPeripheral!
    
    
    
    init(vm: SharedViewModel) {
        self.sharedVM = vm
        super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
        Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 0.1, repeats: true) { timer in
            self.methodThatChangeValueOfString()
        }
    }
    ...

// then used in the view struct like this
struct SessionsView: View {
    @StateObject var sharedVM: SharedViewModel = SharedViewModel()
    @EnvironmentObject var myWeights: StoredWeights
```

Comment: you need to put the answer and then back it up with the reference

Comment: elaborate please, do you mean put my code up?

Comment: Add the protocol that you used  with  a sample code

Comment: sounds good, hopefully this helps someone! Let me know if there is any other way I can make my answer better